# clojure - explanation of 'apply' in this context

Tags: clojure

I understand how apply works in a simple expression like this:

```
(apply + '(1 2 3))
```

I have come across a more complex example in a book I am reading.

```
(def make
     (fn [class & args]
       (let [seeded {:__class_symbol__ (:__own_symbol__ class)}
             constructor  (:add-instance-values (:__instance_methods__ class))]
         (apply constructor seeded args))))
```

In the above example, seeded is a map and args is an ArraySeq.

Can anyone explain how apply works in this context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case `(apply constructor seeded args)` is equivalent to calling `(constructor seeded arg0 arg1 arg2 ...)`. It unwraps the last argument (which must be seqable) and appends them one by one to the list before evaluation.

For example, this: `(apply + 1 [2 3])` unrolls to `(+ 1 2 3)`.

It seems to be analogous to:

- `((make) MyClass)` is equivalent to `new MyClass()`
- `((make) MyClass "foo" "bar" 3)` is equivalent to `new MyClass("foo", "bar", 3)`

Comment: This answer is almost right. However, apply only unwraps the *last* argument, not *all*. Try (apply + 1 [2 3] [4 5]) and see it won't work.

Comment: @NielsK Good point, I didn't know that. It is the same in this case (having 2 args), but you're right about more. Thank you.